# Spark performs slower with hardware scaling up

Tags: performance, apache-spark

I am trying to find a fit hardware size for my Spark job. My understanding was that scaling up the number of machines may help speeding up my job, **considering the fact that my job does not have a complex action operation and therefore probably small amount of calculation in the driver program**. However, what I observe is that the job execution speed lowers down when adding resources to Spark. I can reproduce this effect using the following simple job:

- Loading a text file (~100Gb) from HDFS
- Running a simple 'filter' transformation on the RDD, that looks like below:

  ```
  JavaRDD<String> filteredRDD = rdd.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
      public Boolean call(String s) {
          String filter = "FILTER_STRING";
          return s.indexOf(filter) > 0 ? true : false; 
     }
  ```
- Running count() action on the result

The scaling problem shows itself when I scale up the number of machines in the cluster from 4 to 8. Here are some details about the environment:

- Each executor is configured to use 6 GB of memory. Also the HDFS is co-hosted on the same machines.
- Each machine has 24 GB of RAM in total and 12 cores (configured to use 8 for Spark executors).
- Spark is hosted in a YARN cluster.

Any ideas why I am not getting the degree of scalabilty I expect from Spark?

Comment: how much partitions are there in your rdd? How many cores each machine has? memory? Please provide some details. What do you see in spark UI

Comment: @IgorBerman I edited the question to give more on the test env. As for the number of partitions, I am letting Spark decide (which creates partitions for each HDFS block, in my case 128MB).
It is extremely hard for me to access the UI, but everything is OK in the logs. All executors are launched and no errors that I can see. Should I look for something specific in the logs?

Comment: What are the times and what kind of disk do you use?

Comment: @zero323 I use SSD as disk. No RAID. I get 6-7 seconds responses when using 4 machines, 12 when scale to 8 and  ~30 seconds when  go up to 16.

Comment: And how do you measure the time? Any particular action?

Comment: Hmmm... how about network connection? All the machines are in the same hosting area? Do they have similar network-connection?

Comment: @jarasss yes, they are all alike and and in one area.

Comment: @zero323 I used count. I edited my question again to cover your point. thnx.

Comment: It is just a wild guess but with fast disks and trivial tasks you may be wasting all gains from increased parallelism on additional scheduling and communication. Also there could some data locality issues. One thing you can try is to artificially increase tasks cost (even with simply thread sleep ...) and see how your clusters behave then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark on EMR : Time for running data in EMR didn't reduce when no of nodes increases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987974/spark-on-emr-time-for-running-data-in-emr-didnt-reduce-when-no-of-nodes-incre)

Comment: @eliasah I tried to isolate many things. Keep the data big enough, reduce the size of the action to minimize the impact of data transfer, etc. I think this question is much more focused on a very specific part (reading a file in parallel)

Comment: As @zero323 said, it all goes into the level of parallelism. Scheduling and communications are and will always be bottlenecks of any distributed system.

Comment: @zero323 Thank you. Indeed I tried adding sleep to tasks in my tests and it resulted into numbers that make sense (they perform better with more machines). But that does not prove anything because in that case, increasing the number of nodes leads to reduced number of serial task cycles (which is not the case). What I don't understand is that why reading a file from HDFS (that claims to be distributed on the block level and therefore solve the locality problem) and doing almost nothing on it may result in a scheduling/communication overhead that big. Of course it maybe a question of design.

Comment: I really would try to "fix" your access to spark ui, since there are many details/problems that usually you see in spark metrics and which give you directions for further investigations/improvements. You will see there GC problems, locality problems, timeline for the task execution. Without these details we can only guess. I would say that 6GB per executor when each partition has 128MB on disk is too small(do you have compression?), but once again it's hard to tell without any metrics visible.

Comment: really I don't agree with accepted answer. I have similar use cases in production which digest text files and if everything is tuned then we see scalability...spark is built for this. I believe the bottleneck is somewhere else.  e.g. if you uploaded text file into hdfs when you had only 4 machines - then yes, every other machine will introduce additional communication, since blocks won't be collocated with new machines, but if you distribute your file properly on all machines - I hardly believe that cost of sending per partition count will cost you too much compared to processing itself

Comment: I agree that you should fix your access to the UI. Spark UI can give you a lot of insights about your job like the number of task executed per executor (JVM). It can also tell you if your data is skewed (more data into a task). If the number of partitions is fixed (due to the number of blocks) and you are not repartitioning, adding more machines means that if the number of partitions is less that what it could be with a full utilisation (1 task per executor) there are machines not used. So in that case time can increase slightly because of synchronisation of more nodes/executors.

Comment: Since you are loading data from HDFS. I'll suggest ot check HDFS block, and hdfs replication factor for the file. If that 100GB's block are not present in all the nodes, spark will be moving data across all the nodes to do calculation, leading to what you are experiencing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to lot of comments, I think I found what was wrong with my cluster. The idea of HDFS 'replication factor' being at least a part of the problem was a very good clue.

In order to test, I changed replication factor of HDFS to the number of cluster nodes and re-ran the tests, and I got scalable results. But I was not convinced about the reason behind this behavior, because Spark claims to consider data locality in assigning partitions to executors and even with the default replication level (3), Spark should have enough room to assign partitions evenly. With some more investigation I figured out that this may not be the case if YARN (or any other cluster manager) decide to share a physical machine with more than one executor and not to use all the machines. In that case there may be HDFS blocks that are not local to any executor, which will result in data transfer across network and the scaling problem that I observed.

Comment: When you add new nodes to Hadoop you need to rebalance the HDFS so that data will spread evenly between the nodes.

Comment: @DanielHaviv That's true. But that was not my case because I started my HDFS fresh and copied the test file in order to ensure the files are in balance.

Comment: So is there any work around without changing replication to cover the whole cluster? Like knowing why YARN may fail assigning the wrong container to the wrong machine?

Comment: @Maziyar. I couldn't find any other workarounds since I posted the question. Note that while HDFS/Spark could do a better job allocating the partitions, they are not doing it wrong! Problem is that data locality breaks when data starts shuffling around the cluster. So you (as the programmer) should have this design in mind and  tune your code to minimize the shuffling of the data.

Comment: I appreciate your answer @asaad. The problem is, most of ML and MlLib functions are forced to do the shuffling before you can go to the next step. But I will look into caching and broadcasting to see if I can make it work. (Actually it is very fast alone, only when I mix it with Stanford CoreNLP it becomes a bit slower). Thanks for your reply again.